# display ng-repeat items if id usera place in array AngularJS MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have done the display of all blackboard created by the user. But now I want to make access to those blackboards for other users. So I need to field in database which depends on user id assignment, add another id users. And here is problem, how to make a loop which print all blackboads but if in the board.users [] is exists a user._id.

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="board in boards" >

      <a href="b/{{board._id}}">
          <div>{{board.name}}</div>
        </a>
    </li>
```

I useing mongodb with mongoose and nodejs+angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use ng-if i-e:

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="board in boards" >

  <a ng-if="board.user_id" href="b/{{board._id}}">
      <div>{{board.name}}</div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: It will work if In board.users[firstID, secondID], I make ng-if="board.users == user._id"? ng-if it searches the arrays too?

Comment: No it's will not search array. You've to make another ng-repeat to get user_id or you can pust user_id in board object.

Comment: Which option would be most meaningful? ng-repeat every time the user logs in and checks if he has access is probably wrong?

Comment: For me you must have user object in board object except to have array.
Like :-
          `$scope.boards[{userObj:{}}] `

Comment: Sorry, I still dont understand, I must make this after side AngularJS controller yes? $scope.boards.userObj[{here will be all objects with _id users who have access to board}] but for example i will have 3 objects, still dont know how to display only if have access

Comment: 1 option: Boy In boards array each board object, you should have only one user object which have access to board for verification and you can test this in controller.

2 option: You can check in controller and splice those element which user don't have board permission.

Comment: For second option, so i think that better is this ng-repeat or angular.foreach with return true or false that is there _id or no. Can u make example for first option??? on plnkr ?? ,, and one more question can we Mix and do things on the front and back-end or we should code only after one side?

Comment: Yes you can mix, you can create fiddle then share with me.